# Powershell Runspaces, Multithreading, w/ WPF GUI - 2nd additional thread locking up

Tags: wpf, multithreading, powershell

I have a background thread working for the System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer. I am trying to make an additional thread with a loop in it to keep track of mediaposition etc and report it back to the GUI. The problem I'm having is that launching a second thread seems to be locking up the UI, below is an example of what I am trying.

I am expecting the Track button to start a loop on a background thread and update the UI, and it is, but it is semi-locking up as if I'm running the loop in the same thread even though I am getting the updates I lose all control of the UI

If I put the while loop inside the dispatcher instead of around it, it completely locks up without updating the UI at all.

Example.ps1

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework, System.Drawing, System.Windows.Forms, WindowsFormsIntegration, presentationCore

$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)          

[xml]$xaml = '
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MultithreadedGUI" Height="300" Width="400">
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock Name="lblStatus" Text="NothingPlaying"/>
        <Button Name="btn_stop" Canvas.Top="20" Content="Stop" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="76" Margin="10,0"/>
        <Button Name="btn_play" Canvas.Top="60" Content="PlayTrack" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="85" Margin="10,0"/>
        <Button Name="btn_track" Canvas.Top="100" Content="TrackTime" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="85" Margin="10,0"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
'
  
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
$syncHash.mediaPlayer=New-Object system.windows.media.mediaplayer

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        Write-Output "Adding $($_.Name)"
        $syncHash.Add($_.Name,$syncHash.Window.FindName($_.Name))
    } catch {
        throw
    }
}

# check if a command is still running when exiting the GUI
$syncHash.Window.add_Closing({
    if ($Session -ne $null -and $Handle.IsCompleted -eq $false) {
        [Windows.MessageBox]::Show('A command is still running.')
        # the event object is automatically passed through as $_
        $_.Cancel = $true
    }
})

# close the runspace cleanly when exiting the GUI
$syncHash.Window.add_Closed({
    if ($Session -ne $null) {$Session.EndInvoke($Handle)}
    $newRunspace.Close()
})
##Stop and Close MediaPlayer
$btn_stop=$syncHash.Window.FindName("btn_stop")
$btn_stop.Add_Click({
    $syncHash.mediaPlayer.Stop()
    $syncHash.mediaPlayer.Close()
})
##Play Media
$btn_play=$syncHash.Window.FindName("btn_play")
$btn_play.Add_Click({
    $global:Session = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke(
            [action]{
    $syncHash.mediaPlayer.Position=New-Object System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    $syncHash.mediaPlayer.open($syncHash.FullName)
    $syncHash.mediaPlayer.Play()
                },"Normal"
        )
    })

    $Session.Runspace = $newRunspace
    $global:Handle = $Session.BeginInvoke()
})
##Is this running in a seperate thread?
$btn_track=$syncHash.Window.FindName("btn_track")
$btn_track.Add_Click({
    $global:Tracker = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({
        while($true){
            $syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.invoke(
                [action]{
                    $syncHash.lblStatus.Text=$syncHash.mediaPlayer.Position
                },"Normal"
            )
        }
    })
    $Tracker.Runspace = $newRunspace
    $global:Handle2 = $Tracker.BeginInvoke()
})
## Get MP3 File
$getFile=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
    InitialDirectory="$env:UserProfile\Music"
    Title='Select a MP3 file...'
    Filter='MP3 (*.mp3)|*.mp3'
}
$filePicker=$getFile.ShowDialog()
if($getFile.Filename -ne ""){
    $syncHash.FullName=$getFile.Filename
}

$syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Rather than your `While` loop you might setup an event driven [timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) that check the status every few 100ms. As an aside: [`$Null` should be at the lefthandside of the comparison operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-null#checking-for-null)

Comment: iRon's advice is worth heeding; since you're in control of playback, you don't even need to query the media player for its position and just use a stopwatch to update a label based on a timer. The immediate problem is that you're creating a tight loop; inserting a sleep helps, say `Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200`